# Java - global variables not working in mouse event functions

Tags: java, sql, null, mouseevent

Im creating small social network in java. I am having trouble with a function that is supposed to close the program and delete their record from an sql table. I am trying to pass in their username from my usual global variable, but it is outputting as null?

```
public class Wall extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static String _Username = "example";

private void buttonExitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    if(_Username != null)
    {        
        String sql = "DELETE FROM UsersOnline WHERE username = '" +          (Wall._Username)+"';";

        System.out.println(sql);
        System.out.println(Wall._Username);
        try
        {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("SQL update cannot be performed: _Username == null");
    }
}     

Output:
DELETE FROM UsersOnline WHERE username = 'null';
null
```

This problem is particularly annoying as the sql is still valid with null it just doesn't do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In this case 'null' is valid String parameter for SQL. 'null' is NOT EQUAL to null. Add null check before your query and code alternative action you would like to execute.

Comment: Thats why I am asking, I need _Username to make it into the function, I don't understand why it is re-initializing to null

Comment: Wall._Username must be set to null somewhere in your code (outside that that which is posted), seeing that it is initialized to "example". The question then becomes: where?

Comment: Thanks @copeg and DesirePRG, its always the little things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether this works.

```
public static final String _Username = "example";
```

And if it does, it means that somwhere in your code _Username has been changed after the class loaded and before the mouse event happened.